# Amplifier to ADC to Raspberry PI 4 via I2C

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, adc, raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm fairly new to this so any suggestion is welcome. If this is not the place to ask questions like this let me know and I will remove it.

My goal: I have a small oxygen cell which generates a millivolt signal (10 mV to 60 mV). I want to amplify this signal with an op-amp. The amplified signal will then be send to a ADC to then be read with a Raspberry PI 4 via i2c.

The chips chosen TLV2372 and MCP3427UN and I have made the following diagram.

[image]

Will this setup reach my goal and if not what should I change and why?

Comment: The gain (x75) looks ok for me. I wish C1 & C2 were the same value (don't know but may be that 330nF). Place one more decoupling, so all the devices have at least one. Place one 0.1u and a bulk (10uF?) at the power entry point(s). Take care the GND wiring.... then you can start... 3, 2, 1 now.

Comment: It's a high gain, taking a relatively small signal into a slow 16 bit ADC. The input offset voltage of the amplifier looks to be similar in magnitude to your input signal. I doubt you will get any meaningful signal at 16 bit resolution. An instrumentation amp, rather than an op amp, maybe more suitable for this.

Comment: What is your end goal? What are you using this for?

Comment: @Ryan the end goal is to regulate an flow of oxygen into a closed loop based on the sensor reading the average oxygen in the loop will be about 32% wich translates to about 22mV from the sensor.

Comment: Maybe a 24bit sigma/delta converter might obviate the need for the opamp? Something like a HX711 at a pinch?   I’ve not read the datasheet, so I’d suggest some research. Specs like noise become more critical at these low voltages.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is only to have a differential gain of Adiff=75 and -3 dB BW of 1.5 Hz, then that looks good. But it is only a 1st order non-inverting LPF.  The bad part is the common mode gain is > 30 dB in the 3kHZ range which is not good for noise immunity.

Therefore you should choose a design with high CMRR rather than high CM gain in the noise band.

So 1st define the required CMRR and spectral noise.

Then choose a design such as a balanced impedance high gain INA with a LPF.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to back the analog filtering off a bit as the ADC can do 15SPS, but it also depends on how noisy the sensor and opamp get and what your SNR needs to be.

Also, if the raspberry pi does not have I2C pullups you will most likely need them on this board.

Comment: Is it in the native pixel resolution?

Comment: Good catch, I2C pull-up-s